# Is it possible to spawn Flows in Akka-Streams based on another stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Following example of `BroadcastHub` it is possible to spawn dynamically workers that listen to the same producer. But this spawning must be done explicitly in code. I wonder if it can be coded as a reaction of an event in a stream.

In the example below I would like to spawn 2 more workers after receiving the "Spawn" message in the `spawns` stream. Is it possible?

```
package com.example

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.{BroadcastHub, Flow, Keep, Sink, Source}

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object TestApp extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("system")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val ticks = Source.tick(0.second, 1.second, "Tick").take(10)

  val broadcaster = ticks.toMat(BroadcastHub.sink(bufferSize = 16))(Keep.right).run()

  def prefixFlow(tag:String) = Flow[String].map(_ + s" from $tag").to(Sink.foreach(println))

  // Print out messages from the producer in two independent consumers
  broadcaster.runWith(prefixFlow("1"))
  broadcaster.runWith(prefixFlow("2"))

  // Is it possible to spawn more flows based on another stream?
  val spawns = Source.tick(2.second, 3.second, "Spawn").take(2)
  // spawns.foreach(broadcaster.runWith(prefixFlow("XXX"))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your specific example, could you be looking for a simple `map`?

```
val spawns = Source
  .tick(2.second, 3.second, "Spawn")
  .take(2)
  .map(_ ⇒ broadcaster.runWith(prefixFlow("XXX")))
  .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Yeah, sometimes simple solutions are the ones that matter :)